# Why was Mundungus so loyal to Dumbledore?

Tags: harry-potter, albus-dumbledore

[From this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/85497/13716),

> “He’s useful,” Sirius muttered. “Knows all the crooks — well, he would, seeing as he’s one himself. **But he’s also very loyal to Dumbledore, who helped him out of a tight spot once.**

**What did Dumbledore do for Mundungus that would cause him to be so loyal**, to the point that the Order wants him to help with such an important task as moving Harry in the last book? Sure, Moody didn't trust him completely, but they still thought he was one of the useable people, and while Dumbledore was around he seemed to trust Mundungus as much as he trusted others.

Why was Mundungus unquestionably (or was he?) loyal to Dumbledore?

Comment: You stole that from my question.

Comment: I Think the answer might be "But he’s also very loyal to Dumbledore, who helped him out of a tight spot once."

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why was Mundungus used to move Harry?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/85495/why-was-mundungus-used-to-move-harry)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the passage you quoted is all we know about Mundungus’s loyalty to Dumbledore.

It’s not discussed again in the books, I don’t know of any interviews about it, and there’s been no mention of it on Pottermore.

Given Mundungus’s criminal tendencies, I think the most likely explanation is that he was caught or accused of doing something really bad (worse than petty theft), and Dumbledore playing a significant part in exonerating him.

As Dung was following Harry shortly after the *Order of the Phoenix* was reassembled, I think we can assume that he was probably in the original Order. I would thus guess that he was framed for something nasty during the First Wizarding War, and Dumbledore’s testimony and/or evidence stopped him from going to Azkaban. But that’s only a guess; we know almost nothing.

And as for Moody, remember that he doesn’t trust anybody. I wouldn’t read too much into that.

Comment: Dumbledore mentions Mundungus Fletcher as a part of the "old group" at the end of the fourth book when he instructs Professor McGonagall (I think) to send word to everyone who would believe him that Voldemort is back, so, yeas, he was probably in the original order (I don't remember if he was in Moody's photo of the original order in the fifth book though

Comment: @user13267 I don’t think he appears in Moody’s photo; I looked through the passage for an easy quote.